# Multiple different random samples in R

Tags: r, vector, random, boolean, sample

I'm new to R and I've got a question:

```
choice <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
rep(sample(choice, size = 4, replace=FALSE), times = n)
```

always repeats the same vector, e.g. (FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)

However, I want to have n **different** random samples of the vector choice in a new vector (replace must be FALSE, because only 1 in 4 elements should be TRUE).

Which function should I choose? I'm not allowed to use for-loops.

Comment: It's what `rep` does, it repeats the input multiple times (sample function is called once, it returns a vector that is repeated n times by rep). To perform sample() multiple times you can use lapply/sapply or replicate

Comment: What does it mean "*I'm not allowed to use for-loop*"? Define a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replicate`. It returns a matrix, which you can then turn into a vector.

```
choice <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
n <- 3
set.seed(42) # for reproducibility
as.vector(replicate(n, sample(choice, size = 4, replace=FALSE)))
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```